# Make rasbian a rolling distro by changing the sources.list

Tags: raspbian, update, raspbian-lite

Been reading. I found out that in debian you can make it a "rolling release" by changing the distribution name to "test" (or something like that, not quite understand). Is there a way to do the same for rasbian? if so what I need to change?

My current `source.list` is:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Does changing `bullseye`, `bullseye-security`, `bullseye-updates` to `test`, `test-security`, `test-updates` respectively will work?

Comment: explore http://deb.debian.org/debian

Comment: You are not using Raspbian.  You are using Debian.  Follow Debian advice.

Comment: Thanks @jsotola I found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jsotola's comment **explore deb.debian.org/debian** I found out that I had to change it to `bookworm` or `sid` like:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free
```